# Add values for matching column and row names

Tags: python, pandas

Quick question that I'm brain-farting on how to best implement. I am generating a matrix to add up how many times two items are found next to each other in a list across a large number of permutations of this list. My code looks something like this:

```
agreement_matrix = pandas.DataFrame(0, index=names, columns=names)
for list in bunch_of_lists:
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        agreement_matrix[list[i]][list[i+1]] += 1
```

It generates an array like:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   2   1   1
B   2   0   1   1
C   1   1   0   2
D   1   1   2   0
```

And because I don't care about order as much I want to add up values so it's like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   4   2   2
B   0   0   2   2
C   0   0   0   4
D   0   0   0   0
```

Is there any fast/simple way to achieve this? I've been toying around with both doing it after generation and trying to do it as I add values.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think your answer is good.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thank you. Just not sure because of OP and their "expected output". :-(

Comment: @OP Something about your expected output seems incorrect. Can you confirm please? Shouldn't A-D be 2? B-D I would imagine should be 2 as well.

Comment: @coldspeed I shouldn't do math in public. I fixed it now, and it seems as though your answer works.

Comment: @Brendan that's why we code (don't do maths by hand :) ) please upvote and accept now you can https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.tri*`:

```
np.triu(df) + np.tril(df).T

array([[0, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Call the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.triu(df) + np.tril(df).T, df.index, df.columns)

   A  B  C  D
A  0  4  2  2
B  0  0  2  2
C  0  0  0  4
D  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick and easy fix. I should note for future viewers that even though my provided example was symmetrical around the diagonal, this appears to work in cases where it's not as well.

Comment: Nice usage of `triu` and `tril`:-)

Answer (score 1):

A pandas solution to avoid the first loop:

```
values=['ABCD'[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,4,100)] # data

df=pd.DataFrame(values)
df[1]=df[0].shift()
df=df.iloc[1:]
df.values.sort(axis=1)
df[2]=1

res=df.pivot_table(2,0,1,np.sum,0)
#
#1  A   B   C   D
#0               
#A  2  14  11  16
#B  0   5   9  13
#C  0   0  10  17
#D  0   0   0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem ..

```
np.triu(df.values*2)#df.values.T+df.values
Out[595]: 
array([[0, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Then you do

```
pd.DataFrame(np.triu(df.values*2), df.index, df.columns)
Out[600]: 
   A  B  C  D
A  0  4  2  2
B  0  0  2  2
C  0  0  0  4
D  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: This appears to only work for values that are symmetrical around the diagonal, unless I'm incorrect.

Comment: @Brendan `#df.values.T+df.values` did you see the mark one :-)